# Spring roo: Linking bootstrap to views

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-roo

I'm still newbie in Spring roo. I finished building the entities and I need to customize the appearance of my application. I want to use bootstrap but I don't know where to reference bootstrap's CDN from. I mean I can't find the `<head>` tag to put the `<link>` inside.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Spring Roo does not include support for Bootstrap. You should include it manually.

Anyway, If you need to use advanced and updated components on your web application, I recommend you to use [gvNIX - Roo Addon Suite](http://www.gvnix.org/en) that includes jQuery, **Bootstrap**, HTML5, CSS3, Datatables, GEO components, etc..

You could check a demo of an application developed using gvNIX [here](http://geo-gvnix.rhcloud.com) (admin | admin).

If you need help about how to install gvNIX on your Spring Roo distribution, follow [this guide](http://jcagarcia.github.io/2015/07/22/how-to-extend-spring-roo/).

Hope this helps,

Regards,